# json_encode not escaping UTF-8 w/PHP 5.2.8

Tags: php, json

It results in illegal JSON when trying to parse with jQuery. The entire document, database connection is encoding in UTF-8.

The code

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo (json_encode($products));
```

This is what is output **(Updated)**:

```
{
  "D8": {
    "title": "Green A\/C U\/V Dye Self-Measure bottle treats 32 véhicules 8 oz. (237 ml)",
    "image": "http:\/\/www.supercool.ac\/wp-content\/uploads\/2011\/10\/D8.png",
    "Description": "<ul>\n<li>Efficace dans le R-134a et R-12 systèmes de réfrigération<\/li>\n<li>Detectable when exposed to U\/V light<\/li>\n<li>Compatible avec PAG, ester, les huiles minérales et<\/li>\n<li>Ne contient pas de solvants!<\/li>\n<li>Will not harm A\/C systems or recovery equipment<\/li>\n<li>Universal A\/C Dye Safe for Hybrid and<br \>\n&nbsp;Véhicules électriques<\/li>\n<li>Partie # D8<\/li>\n<\/ul>\n"
  }
}
```

Shouldn't this be escaped by default? What can I do to escape it?

**Update:**

json_encode was mangling the HTML (the description field). It produced a br tag that was invalid `<br />`, notice the forward slash. I assume this is limited to 5.2.8. To correct this I just stripped the br tags as a temporary solution until I can convince the host to upgrade.

```
preg_replace('/\<br\s\/>/', '', string);
```

Comment: Huh? It should do that by default. Strange

Comment: There are no characters with special meaning in there, it doesn't need escaping.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php - search for utf-8

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ will confirm that that is a valid JSON text.

Comment: @Quentin, that was part of the response, I'll show you the part that breaks. I updated it

Comment: @Quentin it *should* `\uxxxx` encode any non-ASCII characters though, shouldn't it? (Edit: ah, Lee claims it does and that the problem must be elsewhere.)

Comment: @Pekka — It might, depending on what options are given to it, but JSON doesn't require that they are encoded.

Comment: @Quentin ah, good point. I was somehow under the impression it was *required*, but you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codepad.org/oWMMVwsE

PHP will encode the utf8 character.

http://jsfiddle.net/

jQuery can parse it fine.

If your echoing it to the browser, dont forget the browser will interpret the utf8 encoding and display the character. so the json encoded string must be read from CLI or from the source.

Comment: I've viewed it from the source and CLI and still the same results happen. Codepad isn't too relevant because it probably doesn't use the same version of PHP, thanks though.

Comment: The jsfiddle link is the homepage!

Comment: Must have copied it wrong and never realised. Been 2 years since i posted the answer but i presume it was just an example of $.parseJSON() proving that it works as it should. You're not missing out on anything, just look at the jquery docs if you want to know how parseJSON works

Answer (score 1):

Your output has a trailing comma after the last property value:

```
  },
}
```

This is invalid JSON. It looks like your copy of PHP has a severely broken implementation of `json_encode`.

I'd look at trying your code on a clean virtual machine with a fresh install of PHP.

Comment: That was a typo. It breaks on the <br /> tag. The forward slash messes it up. Should json_encode take care of this, or do I have to make sure it's encoded beforehand with htmlentities?